# Scrapy get through ASPNet accept dialog using link

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

Here is the form on a Accept.aspx that I am trying to get through:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Accept.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEwMDUyNjYzMjhkZH2Bd9lP6b10lpPKBuDrSTFYUEXj" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="7D7EA99C" />
    <p class="content" style="text-align:center;"> 
        I have read and understood the above.
    </p>
    <p class="content" style="text-align:center;"> 
        <a href="http://www.some-domain.ca/List.aspx" >Click here to enter the site</a>
    </p>
</form>
```

What I have so far, but doesn't set the cookie:

```
yield FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formname='aspnetForm',
        callback=self.after_accept
)
```

When I inspect the request using the actual page no form data is sent. It's seems to be a straight forward GET request. In my after_accept function I get the Accept.aspx page back instead of List.aspx.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? maybe provide url? What FormRequest.from_response does is take the data from input fields etc. and convert it into a request body for POST request. So by default FormRequest will always be a POST request. The most common issues regarding bad aspx requests have to do with headers, check if the headers your scrapy makes match the website headers.

Comment: Thanks. I have provided the entire form except for some styling to improve readability. My assumption is that clicking the href actually posts the form but when I do that and inspect the results, there is no POST. Just  a GET for that resource (List.aspx).

Comment: Looking at the FormRequest documentation in more detail, I see that its possible to specify the click data element by using the `nr` attribute. However, there is no example provided. Should I be using this?